# How to get latest occurrence of a file and sort by timestamp using AWK in unix

Tags: unix, awk, grep, ls

Below is the sample content of the hb_20190930103450.log file

```
   <------some lines------->
      [2019-09-30 19:55:59] [MERGE] : ####### BEGIN - claim_response - '2016-01-15' - #######
      <------some lines---------> 
      [2019-09-30 20:17:11] [MERGE] : ####### BEGIN - compound_ingred - '2016-01-15' - #######
  <-------some lines---------->
```

here $1 is [2019-09-30, $2 is 20:17:11] and $8 is compound_ingred

I am using this command to get list of lines from a bunch of similar files like hb_20190930103450.log I am using hb_2019*.log which includes BEGIN in a line and get $1, $2,$8 columns from the line which includes BEGIN along with filenames and adding
 them to startdate.txt file.

```
  awk '/BEGIN/ {print FILENAME,$1,$2,$8}' hb_2019*.log > sdate.txt
```

Below is outcome of above command which gives all the files in all the log files

```
hb_20190927121800.log [2019-09-27 20:45:56] ser_message1
hb_20190927121800.log [2019-09-27 20:45:58] claim_response
hb_20190927121800.log [2019-09-27 20:46:00] compound_ingred
hb_20190927121800.log [2019-09-27 20:47:36] pha_ree
hb_20190930103448.log [2019-09-29 10:34:48] ser_message1
hb_20190930103448.log [2019-09-29 11:58:22] claim_response
hb_20190930103448.log [2019-09-29 14:17:28] mcompound_ingred
hb_20190930103448.log [2019-09-29 15:05:48] pha_ree
hb_20190930103450.log [2019-09-30 19:11:25] ser_message1
hb_20190930103450.log [2019-09-30 19:55:59] claim_response
hb_20190930103450.log [2019-09-30 20:17:11] compound_ingred
hb_20190930103450.log [2019-09-30 20:17:13] pha_ree
```

Below is what I am trying but no luck

```
  awk '/BEGIN/ {print FILENAME,$1,$2,$8}' hb_2019*.log |sort|uniq > sdate.txt
```

Does anyone face this and had a success?

sample expected output should look like below with only latest of entries  of tables

```
hb_20190930103450.log [2019-09-30 19:11:25] ser_message1 
hb_20190930103450.log [2019-09-30 19:55:59] claim_response 
hb_20190930103450.log [2019-09-30 20:17:11] compound_ingred 
hb_20190930103450.log [2019-09-30 20:17:13] pha_ree
```

Comment: You could change your `sort | ...` pipe to be `| sort -k 2,2 | tail -n 1`. That will sort lexicographically by the ISO date stamp in column 2 then print the last date line.

Comment: I tried to answer but apparently guessed wrong on what it is you want so please [edit] your question to contain concise, testable sample input (i.e. 2 or 3 small hp*.log file) and the expected output given those input files so no-one else wastes their time guessing.

Comment: `sort -u` is equivalent to `sort | uniq`

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Below is the sample content of the hb_20190930103450.log file

    <------some lines--------->
    [2019-09-30 19:55:59] [MERGE] : ####### BEGIN - claim_response - '2016-01-15' - #######
    <------some lines--------->
$ 1 is [2019-09-30      ----------date
$ 2 is  19:55:59]       --------time
$ 8 is   claim_response  -------tablename

Comment: sample output should look like  below with only latest of entries                                                                                       hb_20190930103450.log [2019-09-30 19:11:25] ser_message1
hb_20190930103450.log [2019-09-30 19:55:59] claim_response
hb_20190930103450.log [2019-09-30 20:17:11] compound_ingred
hb_20190930103450.log [2019-09-30 20:17:13] pha_ree

Comment: @dharani, comments are not meant to post samples, please add them in your post itself and let us know then.

Comment: @dawg tried yours but I have to mention the tail -n n ,which gives the n number of occurances of the table instead of a single latest one

Comment: @dharani, Request you please rephrase your post by adding simple sample of input and sample of expected output in CODE TAGS and let us know then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 posted updated question

Comment: @dharani, no still not clear please don't put dots etc in samples, else we are not getting its full picture, edit it with more near to exact data samples.

Comment: @dharani, I am going to vote this question to close vote, until you edit it with proper details. Lemme know once proper details there will retract it then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I tried to add the sample file , there are multiple similar files with a line including word BEGIN in them , I am trying to get $1,$2,$8 coumns from those files. $8 here is a table name and $1 is date I want to get list of all tables($8) respective to most recent date ($1) only once.

Answer (score 2):

pipe the output to this instead

```
$ ... | sort -k4 -k2,3r | uniq -f3 | sort -k2,3

hb_20190930103448.log [2019-09-29 14:17:28] mcompound_ingred
hb_20190930103450.log [2019-09-30 19:11:25] ser_message1
hb_20190930103450.log [2019-09-30 19:55:59] claim_response
hb_20190930103450.log [2019-09-30 20:17:11] compound_ingred
hb_20190930103450.log [2019-09-30 20:17:13] pha_ree
```

sort by name and time stamp (descending order) and pick the first entry with `uniq`, sort again for time.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is that you have various keys (`ser_message1`, `claim_response`, `compound_ingred`, ...) from which you want the ***youngest** entry per key* off all files `hb_2019*.log`. We can do this easily by keeping track of the times per key. I will make the assumption that the full concatenated set of files is *unordered in time*:

```
$ awk '!/BEGIN/ { next }
       { key=$8; timestring=$1$2 }
       (! (key in time)) || (timestring > time[key]) {
          time[key]=timestring
          msg[key] = FILENAME OFS $1 OFS $2 OFS $8
       }
       END { for(key in time) print msg[key] }
      ' hb_2019*.log | sort -k2,3
```

Answer (score 0):

Another shot in the dark:

```
$ awk '
FNR==1 { b="" }
/BEGIN/ { b=b (b==""?"":ORS) FILENAME OFS $1 OFS $2 OFS $8 }
END { print b }' hb_2019*.log
```

**Update:** Special version for your sample data set, use the above for you actual data (ie. fields `FILENAME, $2, $3, $4` instead of `FILENAME, $1, $2, $8`):

```
$ awk 'FNR==1{b=""}{b=b (b==""?"":ORS) FILENAME OFS $2 OFS $3 OFS $4}END{print b}' hb_201909*
hb_20190930103450.log [2019-09-30 19:11:25] ser_message1
hb_20190930103450.log [2019-09-30 19:55:59] claim_response
hb_20190930103450.log [2019-09-30 20:17:11] compound_ingred
hb_20190930103450.log [2019-09-30 20:17:13] pha_ree
```